# What is wrong with my solution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given a person makes repeated attempts to destroy a target, attempts are made independent of each other. The probability of destroying the target in any attempt is  $.8$. Given that he fails to destroy the target in the first five attempts, the probability that the target is destroyed in the $8^{th}$ attempt is.
If it is a geometric distribution (I think so) then it doesn't matter if he fails to destroy the target in first five attempts (lack of memory) then shouldn't the probability be $(.2)^{7}*(.8)$

Answer (score 0):

Well, what does lack of memory state? It states that $P(X > k+n|X>n)=P(X>k)$ for $k>n$ rather than $P(X > k+n|X>n)=P(X>k+n)$. So you'd get $(0.2)^2\cdot(0.8)$.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the property of "lack of memory".  Consider the simpler problem:

> Given that he fails to destroy the target in the first five attempts, what is the probability that the target is destroyed on the next attempt?

Clearly the answer is $0.8$.  However the next attempt will be the *6th* one, so your reasoning would result in $(0.2)^5 \cdot 0.8$, instead of $0.8$.

Comment: Thanks, Erick I understand now I really misunderstood the property and your example is really helpful